# Adding multiple character count with multiple limits on same page

Tags: jquery

There is an issue adding multiple character counts on a single page. How would I allow for multiple limits without using multiple lines of the same script?

https://jsfiddle.net/r7c3754j/1/

```
var text_max = 80;
$('#character_count').html(text_max + ' remaining');

$('#text_area').keyup(function() {
  var text_length = $('#text_area').val().length;
  var text_remaining = text_max - text_length;

  $('#character_count').html(text_remaining + ' remaining');
});
```

Comment: By definition of `id`, multiple elements cannot have the same `id`. Make `text_area` a class.

Comment: @4castle How could I fix this issue using jquery. It wouldn't make sense to have multiple lines of the same javascript in order to use the character limit for multiple lines.

Comment: @user2680614  _"How could I fix this issue"_ Change `id="text_area"` to `class="text_area"` and `id="character_count"` to `"class="character_count""`, select `$(".text_area")` , `$(".character_count")` elements

Comment: @user2680614 Right, I agree it wouldn't make sense to do that. Using `class` instead of `id` will fix it though with a few other changes. [Like this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r7c3754j/2/)